# Basic question on propositional logic: "John, Michael and Susan are doctors" = p∧q∧r?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

There was a question in an exam I've taken stating that a proposition with a compound subject could also be correctly restated as p∧q∧r. The answer was that it's not the same thing. I want to know if this answer is really correct; if it's not, I will need to argue as to why it is wrong.

I think that a given sentence with a compound subject - say, "John, Michael and Susan are doctors" - could be perfectly restated as "John is a doctor AND Michael is a doctor AND Susan is a doctor"; hence p∧q∧r. But then my knowledge of propositional logic is admittedly very limited.

Thank you all.

Comment: Without further elements, it is hard to answer. In the context of propositional logic, we may asserts that the sentence can be symbolized with $p$ only. The "correct" symbolization depends on the context.

Comment: IMO, no one can assert that "John, Michael and Susan are doctors" and "John is a doctor AND Michael is a doctor AND Susan is a doctor" mean different things.

Comment: The fact that we are discussing a *compound subject* means (to me) that we have left the limited scope of propositional logic and entered the domain of *predicate logic*.  Certainly one can imagine predicates where unpacking a sentence similar to the example here must be done diffferently, e.g. "John, Michael and Susan are friends" would not be equivalent to "John is a friend, and Michael is a friend, and Susan is a friend."  So as Mauro points out, it "depends on the context."